# How to create a function with dynamic input for an R package?

Tags: r, dynamic, r-package

I'm creating an R package. I have a function that needs some dynamic input from the user in order to produce the desired output. I'm currently using `readline()` as the dynamic input method. Problem is I don't know how to make it work for both `roxygen2` `examples`, nor how to properly test it with `testthat` (or any other method).

If there's a better way to get user input that'd be good as well.

Here's a minimal function with the same issues as my function.

```
#' Dynamic Input Example
#'
#' @param input A number
#'
#' @return Console input times 2 minus 1
#' @export
#'
#' @examples
#' exampler(4)
exampler <- function(input){
  dynamic_input <- as.numeric(readline(prompt=paste("Give a value between", input*3-1, "and", input*7+2)))
  return(dynamic_input*2-1)
}
```

Comment: Use `\dontrun` in your example to exempt it from the example-testing. The "testthat" tests  can be done using the excellent mockery package (it makes it easy to mock the `readline` function during the test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this syntax to prevent functions examples from being run during check:

```
#' @examples \dontrun{interactive_function()}
```

And for the test suite we can use the following (needs the `mockery` package):

```
test_that("interactive_function works with defaults", {

    mockery::stub(interactive_function, "readline", "dummy return value for mock function")
 
    testvalue <- interactive_function()

    [testcode ...]
 
})
```

With that code, mockery will replace the `readline` function during the test if it is called by the `interactive_function` and return "dummy return value for mock function". `mockery` also offers functions to track function calls and even the arguments that were used when calling the functions. All very handy stuff ;)

Comment: I was aware of the ```\dontrun{}``` but I hoped that there was another option, considering as well CRAN submission later on.

As for testing, ```mockery``` looks neat, only issue is, how would it behave with different calls to ```readline()``` or a loop?

Comment: You can pass mockery a list of return values and it will return each of the entries in subsequent calls ;) ... And regarding CRAN: I'd assume they are fine with \dontrun since there is often no way around it (any many packages on CRAN make use of ir)

Comment: NVM, got the grasp on how mock+stub work, thanks!

Comment: In order to use the "variable return values" functionality you'd have to use another `mockery` function (see [here](https://github.com/r-lib/mockery))

Comment: Also, it is easier to help you if you'd open another question for this new task. I' will make sure to try and help you though ;)